# Change the selected option of multiple dropdowns with a single trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple dropdowns in separate sections which represent different views of the same dataset similar to below. I want to change all of the dropdowns with any of the selections, but I can't find a working solution.

```
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Making any selection should change all of the others, but it needs to be a dynamic solution, I might have a high number of selects on a page!

I can't get much further than a class based change function, followed by a class based each function, I'm sure the answer is there but I've only found answers to similar questions which rely on a single "master" dropdown to trigger the events of the others.

Many thanks

**Solution**
I've made a rookie mistake, most of the answers I already found that I thought should work, do work. I'm using a funny new framework on my front end, and it needs an additional event to fire to make the dropdown *look* like it was selected. The behavior of the dropdown was working exactly as expected all along.

**How to avoid this rookie mistake**
I should fiddle my own work if I expect something is not working as it should (and before posting). I would have realized my error much faster.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what happen when anyone change?? all need to reset or anything else  ?

Comment: When anyone changes, the others also change to reflect it, so if value="1" is selected on one, value="1" will be selected on all of the others as well @DevsiOdedra

Comment: just use $('.select').val($(this).val()); in on change event.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply you can get value and set it as below**

```js
$(document).on('change', '.select', function(e){

  var val = $(this).val();
  
  $(".select").val(val);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
            $('.select').change(function(){
                $('.select').val($(this).val());
            })
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectedIndex` when `dropown` change like below. It's works even the `class` is different.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $('select').prop('selectedIndex', $(this)[0].selectedIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
  <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">Foo</option>
  <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
  <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">Foo</option>
  <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
  <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">Foo</option>
  <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A vanilla javascript solution if you prefer it.

```js
var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('select');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function(elem) {
      elem.value = this.value;
    }.bind(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
   <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I do appreciate the vanilla option!